# Call a function after Html5 Validation success

Tags: html

I have Some text boxes and one submit button. I have Used HTML5 'required' validation. Its working fine. Now I want to call a function in button click when HTML5 validation does not find any Error. When The required field is not provided the button click will not call the function.

Comment: You'll need JavaScript for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need some extra help to do this, it could be in the form of plain javascript. Personally, I'd use jQuery to help out as it will make things easier for you and account for any cross-browser consistencies. Whether or not you want to use jQuery your is choice, whether it's appropriate only for this is another conversation, the following example is just a demonstration.

Here's a hypothetical example using jQuery that achieves your validation listening functionality:

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" required>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" required>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" class="input-button" disabled>
</form>
```

​
JS

```
$textInputs = $('input.input-text');
$textInputs.on('keyup', function() {
    var $validTextInputs = $('input.input-text:valid'),
        $submit = $('#submit');
    console.log($textInputs.length, $validTextInputs.length);
    if($textInputs.length === $validTextInputs.length){
        //all text fields are valid
        $submit.attr('disabled', null);
    } else {
        //not all text fields are valid
        $submit.attr('disabled', '');
    }
});​
```

CSS (only let's us know, visually, when the input is valid)

```
.input-text:valid {
    background: green;
}​
```

See the example in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/m6QXc/

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `form.onsubmit` handler. Assuming the form's ID is `form`:

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");
form.onsubmit = function() {
    //Pre-submission validation.

    //Return true or false based on whether the validation passed.
    //return false will prevent the submission the form.
};
```

Comment: @Saikat: Tested and works for me. Have you made sure that the form's ID is `form` before copy/pasting?

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery to trigger function after HTML5 form validation

```
 <form id="myForm">
       <input type="text" class="input-text" required>
       <input type="submit" id="submit" class="input-button" disabled>
    </form>


    $("myForm").submit(function(){
        // Your code    
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try this: [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/e6Hf7/73/) extend it as you need, used jQuery though. You can add whatever you want inside:

```
 $('#exampleForm').submit(function(e){     
          e.preventDefault();     

          // here you can call your own js methods, send form with ajax? 
          // or what ever you want
      });
```

Comment: if i give alert after e.preventDefault the line is not executing.